# Customizing uitableviewcell when using storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I'm doing my project with storyboards and I'm trying to implement a custom `UITableViewCell`.

I would like to do the following in my custom cell:

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize myLabel, myButton;

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]))
    {
       //want to custom setup of properties placed in the cell
       self.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];//this does NOT work
       //and so forth... 
    }
    return self;
}
```

But the background color is not set. It only works when I set the background color of the button in the `tableViewController`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    MyObject *obj = self.myObjects[indexPath.row];
    cell.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];//This works!
    cell.myLabel.text = obj.name;
    return cell;
}
```

And I have trying debugging by setting break points and `NSLog` and the `initWithCoder` gets called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for every cell??
But the background color of the button in the cell does not show when I set it in the custom cell.

Can any help?

Comment: Why not set backgroundColor in storyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `awakeFromNib` method instead of `initWithCoder:` to do any initial customization of the cell. And as mentioned in comments, for simple things like background colors of controls, you can probably just do that in Xcode via the storyboard.